# Include path issues in Eclipse: probably Indexer

Tags: c, eclipse, linux-kernel, include, eclipse-cdt

While I was trying to compile a linux-kernel (v. 2.6.39) in Eclipse CDT, I have a not leaving problem about my include paths. I know this is a well discussed topic in the Internet, but all these solutions didn't fix my errors.

One of the errors is: `**linux/kvm_host.h: No such file or directory**`
one of the marked line in the source code is: `#include < linux/kvm_host.h>`

What I did (and actually expect to solve this problem):

In

- Project Properties

  - C/C++ General
  - - Paths and Symbols

I've added in "Includes", "Library Paths" the include directories: 
e.g.:

```
- /[path-to-kernel]/linux-2.6.39/ 
 - /[path-to-kernel]/linux-2.6.39/include
 - /[path-to-kernel]/linux-2.6.39/include/linux
```

Still (after another make), it hasn't changed a thing.

So what's the matter, can someone give me a hint?

[**Edit**: As i mentioned in the comments, with STRG+Click on a underlined library it opens in my browser, so i believe it's just a problem of the **Indexer** but I think i have tryed everything in its options menu]

I just try to develop a fresh Linux kernel nothing special, I can't  be the first one, doing this with a fresh eclipse.

Comment: Open a terminal in your `/[path-to-kernel]/linux-2.6.39/` and run `find . -name 'kvm_host.h'` Is it found?

Comment: Is it found as `/[path-to-kernel]/linux-2.6.39/include/linux/kvm_host.h`?

Comment: yes exactly, that's the path

Comment: I've found out, [STRG]+[Click on the "missing" header] works, it opens the right header in eclipse. But still it's an error?

Comment: Did you add your paths in the `gnu c` Include directories ? In project properties/ C/c++ general/ path and symbols/includes, i can add include search paths for `Assembly Source`,`gnu c` or `gnu C++`. Did you add the paths to the right language ?

Comment: I've got only Assembly and Gnu C, but yes the paths are set here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a new project on the same kernel for the 3rd time it's working now. But still i don't have a clue why :/, since i rebuild the project an the indexer several times. I hope this won't be going on like this.

Thanks for your support!